# Kivy - Black screen -

Tags: python, kivy

I'm working with Kivy in Ubuntu. When I write the widgets on the .kv file, it's all successful, but when I try the code syntax, it just appears a blank screen and I have no idea what to do. Someone please help.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

class BoxLayoutExample(BoxLayout):
    def __int__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs) 
        self.orientation = "vertical"
        b1 = Button(text="A")
        b2 = Button(text="B")
        b3 = Button(text="C")
        self.add_widget(b1)
        self.add_widget(b2)
        self.add_widget(b3)
    

class TheLabApp(App):
    pass


TheLabApp().run()
```

Comment: If you are not using a `kv` file, then you must implement the `build()` method for your `App`.

Comment: I am using, haven't I said the with .kv file it works fine?

Comment: So you are getting a blank screen when using the `kv` file?

Comment: So you are getting a blank screen when you do not use the `kv` file?

Comment: @gersonchadijunior Try to follow what is being said. We have absolutely no clue what exactly you are facing or what might cause the problem based on your provided information. That's why you should describe your problem in detail as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

This line was changed:

```
        super(BoxLayoutExample, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

class BoxLayoutExample(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(BoxLayoutExample, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.orientation = "vertical"
        b1 = Button(text="A")
        b2 = Button(text="B")
        b3 = Button(text="C")
        self.add_widget(b1)
        self.add_widget(b2)
        self.add_widget(b3)


class TheLabApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return BoxLayoutExample()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TheLabApp().run()
```

Comment: Nothing yet, mate. Thank you anyway

Comment: Well, it works in my PC.